# How can I iterate through multiple dataframes in pandas and export each dataframe to seperate excel workbooks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I have about 500 dataframes which I need to format in a specific fashion. I've already written the code to accomplish the formatting, but I need help applying this code to each of the dataframes before I will export to excel using openpyxl. I've attempted to use a for loop, to iterate through a variable which contains all the dataframes, but I keep running into issues. I've read about using dictionaries to store all the dataframes, but I'm not sure this is viable as some of my dataframes may contain the same number and I don't want them to be erroneously excluded as a duplicate. I'm really new to python and pandas, so pardon my ignorance, please!

An examples of my starting data frames:

```
0   Trace     Length
1   domain1     10
2   length1     1
3   length2     2
4   length3     3
5   width1      4
6   width2      5
7   width3      6
```

What it should look like after my formatting function:

```
0   Trace     Length  new_trace  new_length
1   domain1     10       NaN       NaN
2   length1     1      width1       4
3   length2     2      width2       5
4   length3     3      width3       6
```

The code I've written thus far..

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl 

df1 = pd.read_csv(Path...1)
df2 = pd.read_csv(Path...2)
df3 = pd.read_csv(Path...3)

alldfs = (df1, df2, df3)

def format(df): 
    result = (df['Trace'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand = False))
    mask = df['Trace'].str.contains('width')
    df= df.loc[~mask].join(df
    .loc[mask],rsuffix='_new').rename(lambda x:'_'.join(x.split('_')                            [::-1]),axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)   
    df.to_excel(f"new_{df}.xlsx") 




# How do I code this last part of the function so that it dynamically exports the current indexed df in the alldfs variable? 


for df in alldfs: 
    format(df)
```

Any help figuring this out would be so helpful, I've been at it all day, and haven't made much progress. Thanks!

Comment: you return the formatted df in your function. How about directly export the formatted df in your loop `for df in alldfs:` instead of printing it? Then you don't need to store the formatted dfs in a dict and access it later again.

Comment: you will have to create loop to iterate via the folder containing files, you can include your function `format(df): ` at the end of it, with `df.to_excel(f"new_{filename}.xlsx")` in it